# How to make screenshots on Fail using TestCafe

Tags: typescript, testing, automated-tests, testcafe, takesscreenshot

I'm trying to make a screenshot in Testcafe + gherkin on fail but has no success.
I've setup a config file:

```
{
  "browsers": "firefox",
  "screenshots": {
    "path": "reports/screenshots/",
    "takeScreenshotsOnFails": true,
    "pathPattern": "${TIME}.png"
  },
  "reporter": [
    {
      "name": "spec"
    },
    {
      "name": "cucumber-json",
      "output": "reports/generatedReports/newReport.json"
    }
  ],
  "pageLoadTimeout": 1000
}
```

But screenshots is not appear. Other lines are working like browser etc.

Should I use:

```
   await t.takeScreenshot("reports/SCREENSHOT.png");
```

But how to do it only on fail?

Comment: Looks like `takeScreenshotsOnFails` is obsolete, can you try the `takeOnFails` instead? https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/configuration-file.html#screenshotstakeonfails

Comment: Thank you for your response! I've tried both variants but it doesn't help :(

Comment: I've found way through command line adding -S -s reports/screenshots -p "${DATE}_${TIME}.png" But I'd like to make it via config file.

Comment: The [`takeOnFails`](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/configuration-file.html#screenshotstakeonfails) property works for me. My configuration file is as follows:
`{
 "browsers": "firefox",
  "screenshots": {
    "path": "reports/screenshots/",
    "takeOnFails": true,
    "pathPattern": "${TIME}.png"
  },
  "reporter": [
    {
      "name": "spec"
    }
  ],
  "pageLoadTimeout": 1000
}`
Could you specify the testcafe version you are using?

Comment: We're using "testcafe": "1.2.1"

Comment: We introduced the [`screenshot`](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/configuration-file.html#screenshots) object in version 1.6.0 . So to make the configuration file I've provided in my previous comment work update TestCafe to version 1.6.0 or later.

Answer (score 0):

`takeScreenshotsOnFails` has been replaced by `takeOnFails` in [newer versions](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/configuration-file.html#screenshotstakeonfails).

Your configuration file should probably look like this:

```
{
  "browsers": "firefox",
  "screenshots": {
    "path": "reports/screenshots/",
    "{
  "browsers": "firefox",
  "screenshots": {
    "path": "reports/screenshots/",
    "takeOnFails": true,
    "pathPattern": "${TIME}.png"
  },
  "reporter": [
    {
      "name": "spec"
    },
    {
      "name": "cucumber-json",
      "output": "reports/generatedReports/newReport.json"
    }
  ],
  "pageLoadTimeout": 1000
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not pretty sure if this is working on testcafe with gherkin. You can add this code under script into your package.json

```
"test:chrome": "testcafe chrome ./tests -s takeOnFails=true",
```

and run with command `npm run test:chrome`

Answer (score 0):

create a different file or append in the existing file that is **.testcaferc.json**

code is

```
{"screenshotPath": "./screennshots", 
"screenshotPathPatterns": "${DATE}_${TIME}/${FISTURE}.png"}
```

and inside the **package.json** file update the following code

```
"test:chrome": "testcafe chrome ./tests -s takeOnFails = true",
```

Answer (score 0):

You could follow the [official documentation](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402840/guides/advanced-guides/screenshots-and-videos):

> **Take Screenshots When a Test Fails**
>
> You can configure TestCafe to automatically take a screenshot whenever
> a test fails. Use either of the following:
>
> - the `takeOnFails` parameter in the `-s` (`--screenshots`) command line flag,
> - `testcafe chrome tests/sample-fixture.js -s takeOnFails=true`
> - the `takeOnFails` parameter of the `runner.screenshots` API method,

```
runner.screenshots({
    takeOnFails: true
});
```

> - the `screenshots.takeOnfails` configuration file property.

```
{
    "screenshots": {
        "takeOnFails": true
    }
}
```